# launchd exit status issue, launchd not launching program as specified, ideas?

Tags: java, plist, launchd

So basically I have a Java application I'm calling via command line:

```
java -jar -Xmx256m /path/to/tester.jar /path/to/testerconfig.config
```

Running into some issue launching it via launchd.

Basically I have two PLIST files: MBTester_Hourly.plist and MBTester_Kill.plist

MBTester_Hourly.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>MBTester_Hourly</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>java</string>
    <string>-jar</string>
    <string>-Xmx256m</string>
    <string>/path/to/tester.jar</string>
    <string>/path/to/testerconfig.config </string>
</array>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/tester.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/tester.log</string>
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
<key>Minute</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

MBTester_Kill.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"             
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>MBTester_Kill</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>/Users/1eppm/Desktop/commandlineApp/killTester.sh</string>
</array>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/tester.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/log/tester.log</string>
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>45</integer>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So as you can see 'MBTester_Hourly.plist' starts the JAVA application at the start of every hour, and 'MBTester_Kill.plist' calls a script that will kill this process 45 minutes past the hour.

If I manually input the JAVA application launch statement it works and outputs its findings into Terminal.

I even have 3 other machines were I have implemented this with the PLIST files and it works.

I just have two MAC Mini's that refuse to launch the application via configured launchd PLIST files.

I've of course unloaded and loaded each PLIST file:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/Start_Hourly.plist
```

I have also attempted to restart the machine.

Seeing that this process is running on other machines with no issue is very perplexing.

The one thing I did notice is when the PLIST file is scheduled to do its process I ran a 'launchctl list | grep MBTester' it returned something peculiar:

```
launchctl list | grep MBTester
-     78     MBTester_Hourly
-     78     MBTester_Killer
```

Its showing an 'exit status' of 78. What does that mean?

On the machines it actually working on it always has an 'exit status' of 0.

Ideas?

Comment: Issue resolved: /var/log/ directory requires a certain level of permissions to utilize...changed the LOG to the /tmp/ directory worked wonders.

Comment: thank you! that was also my issue.